# Parmetis alternative to PartMeshDual

Tags: mpi, partitioning, mesh, metis

I'm trying to upgrade my code for FE in solid mechanics and wave-propagation. Because `metis/5.1.0` is not properly compiling with my code (whereas `metis/4.0.3` was linking perfectly), I want to switch to [ParMETIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/parmetis/overview).

What ParMETIS function can I substitute for the METIS function `metis_PartMeshDual`?